# How to evaluate correct value of innodb_records_in_range variable of mysql 5.7.28-31?

Tags: mysql, percona

We installed latest [Percona MySQL server v5.7.28-31](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.7/release-notes/Percona-Server-5.7.25-28.html), which is installed via percona repo.

After successfull migration of data and few days of work we met an issue with low performance and high disk IO utilization.

I tried to find out any solution, and found [this known issue](https://jira.percona.com/browse/PS-5783):

> The length of time and resources required for a MySQL query execution increased with a large number of table partitions. [Limiting the Estimation of Records in a Query](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.7/performance/query_limit_records.html#query-limit-estimates) describes the experimental options added to prevent index scans on the partitions and return a specified number of values.

The solution is to change the value of `innodb_records_in_range` and `innodb_force_index_records_in_range` variables. But i can't understand which correct values should be set there.

As i understand these two are count of rows, which will be scanned during the query, but what will mysql optimizer do after scan this rows? Will it use indexes, which should be used as a true way, or it will ignore any indexes and just scan this rows and return incorrect output?
Please help me to understand this two variables.

PS: IF i check query via EXLPAIN on server I see [this correct logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn3zS.jpg) and it uses required indexes.
But on the same server with mysql 5.7.28-31 **at RANDOM time** we see [this incorrect logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs23P.jpg) and it's not using required indexes and here our DB server goes almost down.

PPS: we can't change query, because on other servers we don't have any issues, there is mysql 5.7.23 installed.
Is it really necessary to downgrade mysql minor version, or it is possible to set this values correct?